# Create a custom NewtonSoft JSon Converter

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following JSon which I am parsing using NewtonSoft JSon:

```
{
  "page" : 0,
  "listings" : [ 
    {
      "data" : { "name" : "Name 1", "id" : "id1" },
      "media" : {
        "images" : [ 
          { "title" : "image1", "url" : "http://www.d.com/image1" }, 
          { "title" : "image2", "url" : "http://www.d.com/image3" }, 
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "data" : { "name" : "Name 2", "id" : "id2" },
      "media" : {
        "images" : [ 
          { "title" : "image3", "url" : "http://www.d.com/image3" }, 
          { "title" : "image4", "url" : "http://www.d.com/image4" }, 
        ]
      }
    },

 }
```

The C# object is as follows:

```
public class Result {

  [JsonProperty("page")]
  public Int32 Page { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("listings")]
  public List<Listing> Listings { get; set; }

} // PropertyResult

public class Listing {

  [JsonProperty("data")]
  public ListingData Data { get; set; }    

  [JsonProperty("media")]
  public ListingMedia Media{ get; set; }    

}

public class ListingData {

  [JsonProperty("id")]
  public Int32 Id { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("name")]
  public String Name { get; set; }

}

public class ListingMedia {

  [JsonProperty("images")]
  public IList<ListingMediaImage> Images { get; set; }

}

public class ListingMediaImage {

  [JsonProperty("title")]
  public String Title { get; set; }

  [JsonProperty("url")]
  public String Url { get; set; }

}
```

I am able to parse the ResultPage but not the Listings.

Then I tried a converter:

```
public class ResultConverter : JsonConverter {

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) {
    return (objectType == typeof(Result));
  }

  public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {

    JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
    Result result = jo.ToObject<Result>();
    result.Listings.Data = jo.SelectToken("listings.data").ToObject<ResultData>();
    result.Listings.Images = jo.SelectToken("listings.media").ToObject<ResultMedia>();
    return result;


  }

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }

}
```

This does not work. 
Does anyone knows how should I create the converter?

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ `JsonProperty` should be fine. @Miguel How are you deserializing it? What actually ends up in the listings property, `null`?

Comment: Using the normal deserializeobject and passing the converter

Comment: Try to use JsonConvert.Deserialize<Result> for deserialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JSON markup does not match your .NET classes, so the deserialization is failing, for these reasons:

1. You are expecting `ListingData.Id` to be an integer, but your JSON uses alphanumeric `id` values
2. You haven't closed your `listings` array
3. You may need to get rid of the extra trailing commas

Fix the `listings[n].data.id` values or change the data type for `ListingData.Id` to a `String`, and clean up the JSON syntax errors, and you'll be all set.

You really don't need a custom converter here; your markup is pretty standard. Here's valid JSON markup that can be deserialized into your current .NET classes:

```
string json = @"{
    ""page"" : 0,
    ""listings"" : [{
        ""data"" : { ""name"" : ""Name 1"", ""id"" : ""1"" },
        ""media"" : {
            ""images"" : [ 
                { ""title"" : ""image1"", ""url"" : ""http://www.d.com/image1"" }, 
                { ""title"" : ""image2"", ""url"" : ""http://www.d.com/image3"" } 
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        ""data"" : { ""name"" : ""Name 2"", ""id"" : ""2"" },
        ""media"" : {
            ""images"" : [ 
                { ""title"" : ""image3"", ""url"" : ""http://www.d.com/image3"" }, 
                { ""title"" : ""image4"", ""url"" : ""http://www.d.com/image4"" } 
            ]
        }
    }]
}";

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(json);
```

Your IDE/debugger provides very useful error messages. In this case, I learned everything I needed to fix in the JSON by inspecting the errors thrown by the Newtonsoft library. Please make sure to debug your code properly, and these issues usually sort themselves out.